# Copy a hidden template and put after template sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have created my worksheet with a template sheet. I also create a button to copy the template sheet and put any new created sheets after the template sheet.

Everything is still OK if the 'Template' is visible. When I hide the 'Template', only the latest created sheet is visible, other are auto hidden.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could you please have a look at my script and advise me how to fix that? I want any new created sheet will be visible and put after the hidden template sheet.

Here is my script

```
Sub NewSheet()
    Dim newWS As Worksheet
    Dim TemplateWS As Worksheet
    Dim newWSName As String
      
Retry:
    newWSName = InputBox("Enter Activity name.", "New Sheet Name")
    If newWSName = "" Then Exit Sub

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = newWSName Then
            MsgBox newWSName & " exist already. Pick another name.", vbExclamation, "Sheet Name Exists"
            GoTo Retry
        End If

    Next ws
    
    Set TemplateWS = Sheet7
    TemplateWS.Activate
    TemplateWS.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("template 1")
    ActiveSheet.Name = newWSName
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'Summary'!A1", TextToDisplay:="Click to Summary"
    ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 19
    
End Sub
```

Thank you so much as always.

Comment: Put `ActiveSheet.Visible = True` after `ActiveSheet.Name = newWSName`

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, I have tried with your script, but it didn't work. Only the latest created sheet is visible, others are auto-hidden. Is there another way?

Comment: Does anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a copied sheet becomes the active sheet but this doesn't happen if the copied sheet is hidden. Solution is to make template visible, copy and then hide.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NewSheet()

    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWSName As String
      
Retry:
    newWSName = InputBox("Enter Activity name.", "New Sheet Name")
    If newWSName = "" Then Exit Sub

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = newWSName Then
            MsgBox newWSName & " exist already. Pick another name.", vbExclamation, "Sheet Name Exists"
            GoTo Retry
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Set wsTemplate = Sheets("Template 1")
    wsTemplate.Visible = True
    wsTemplate.Copy After:=wsTemplate
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = newWSName
        .Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
         SubAddress:="'Summary'!A1", _
         TextToDisplay:="Click to Summary"
        .Tab.ColorIndex = 19
    End With
    wsTemplate.Visible = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @CDP1802. It is exactly I look for. You're the best.